# how to get the selected date of month calendar in masked textbox c#

Tags: c#-4.0

```
 private void monthCalendar1_DateChanged(object sender, DateRangeEventArgs e)
    {

        this.maskedTextBox1.Text = monthCalendar1.SelectionStart.ToShortDateString();

    }
```

The date is not in correct format, it should be like 12/03/2015

[image: date not in correct format]

Comment: improve question formatting please

Answer (score 1):

If you always want to have your format like `12/03/2015` no matter in what part of the world your application runs, then you may use this:

```
private void monthCalendar1_DateChanged(object sender, DateRangeEventArgs e)
{
    this.maskedTextBox1.Text = monthCalendar1.SelectionStart.ToString("MM\\/dd\\/yyyy");
}
```

Tha backslashes are needed to escape the slashes, which would otherwise be replaced by local seperator characters.